# Hide make targets from shell when users autocomplete in bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete, make

Is there a way to flag some targets in a `Makefile` so that they don't appear at all in the shell when the user types `make` and then presses `Tab` ?
I am having a `Makefile` with too many recipes and I don't want them all to appear in the shell autocompletion when a users presses `Tab` looking for targets.

Comment: @derobert bash, added tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After studying the problem and coming up with a solution that I wrote in the first answer, I realized that there is another **very simple** way.

Just start the target's names you don't want to show beginning with a **dot**.

Example:

```
.PHONY: foo .hiddentarget
foo: foo.x .hiddentarget
foo.x: foo.c
        touch foo.x
.hiddentarget: foo.x
        echo foo.x ok, I believe
```

And that's all you need!

I came to this idea after trying to figure out how to prevent a target named **.HIDDENGOALS** being called by mistake and run all hidden goals. :)

**Warning** Although I don't see any, I'm not sure if there isn't any side effect on using target names like this "**.targetname**" (starting with a dot).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for nested hidden files, i.e. `foo/.hidden: ...`, `bar/.hidden: ...`, `.hidden: foo/.hidden bar/.hidden`; these will still show up, so some additional gymnastics is required.

Comment: I'm not sure if I followed you @FilipDupanović. This is for hiding _targets_, not _files_.

Comment: That time when you google and find your own answer.... :D

Comment: I feel you - happened a few times to me too but more often where I was asking the question ;) One problem/missing feature of this approach, I think, is that you can't hide goals that are actually file names which always show up(?) So in your example it's not possible to hide the foo.x goal.

Answer (score 1):

To hide some targets, you'd need to hack the autocompletion function of your shell. `bash` uses `/etc/bash_completion` and `/etc/bash_completion.d/*`for that.

Can't recall how tcsh does it.

Answer (score 1):

I've observed that this also works by starting the target with an underscore

```
_hiddentarget:
    @echo "Running hidden target"
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** Best to read the other answer (target name starting with a dot). But I'll let this answer here, as the programming part may help other similar issues.

Ok, it took me some time to come up with a solution. This is a (good) draft, and hopefully it will do the job right.

You must edit the file 
**/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make**
(for Debian Wheezy, or some similar to your system)

In my current version, line numbers 70 to 73 have the code:

```
70         COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$( make -qp $makef $makef_dir 2>/dev/null | \
71             awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ \
72             {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}' )" \
73             -- "$cur" ) )
```

Replace then for the foloowing code:

```
 70         HIDDENGOALS="$(make -qp | grep '^\.HIDDENGOALS:' | cut -d' ' -f2- | sed 's/ /\\|/g')"
 71         if [[ "$HIDDENGOALS" == "" || "$HIDDENGOALS" == ".HIDDENGOALS:" ]]; then
 72             COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$( make -qp $makef $makef_dir 2>/dev/null | \
 73                 awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ \
 74                 {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}' )" \
 75                 -- "$cur" ) )
 76         else
 77             COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$( make -qp $makef $makef_dir 2>/dev/null | \
 78                 awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ \
 79                 {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}' \
 80                 | grep -ve "$HIDDENGOALS" )" \
 81                 -- "$cur" ) )
```

Now inside your `makefile` you can use the following **special target** to hide goals from bash autocompletion:

```
 .HIDDENGOALS: somegoal anothergoal goalstohide
```

much like a `.PHONY` special target (there are some differences).

**Careful**:

**(I)** As this solution works through a `grep -ev`, the special target isn't quite so. It will use anything in the line to match just the way a Regular Expression does.

So, if you have a target, say, `copy2`, and another `copy`, writting

```
 .HIDDENGOALS: copy
```

will hide both goals!

I let the solution to this behavior as an exercise to the reader! ;)

**(II)** Another thing to notice, the `:` is hardcoded to be next to `.HIDDENGOALS:`, meaning that although targets allow **spaces** like `.PHONY :`, this special hack doesn't.

**(III)** I think it would be better to edit a local file instead of **/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make**, to avoid losing the information when an upgrade comes. But I did not tested any options. If you know, please comment and I'll update this answer.

**(IV)** There is a slight chance of a *curious* run the very target **.HIDDENGOALS** with a `make .HIDDENGOALS`. That would run all hidden goals. And autocompleting the name wasn't possible, which lead me to the other quite simple answer!

Comment: What are the odds that you would end up googling some problem years later just to find out that the guy who gives you the answer is yourself? :)